# Should objects further down a hierarchy reference the root?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My stack is ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework 6.1, code-first, SQL Server.

I'm working on an application which involves multiple schools, each of which have courses (each which have sections) and students. These form hierarchies of related objects, which are each rooted by a single school instance.

Basic layout so far:
One school has many courses and students
One course has many sections

Simplified versions of the models follow.

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrolment> Enrolments { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CourseSection> CourseSections { get; set; }
}

public class CourseSection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrolment> Enrolments { get; set; }
}
```

There are other models and relationships involved, but this should be enough to form the basis for my question.

A course section is related to a course, which in turn relates to a school. Given a course section, I can determine the school it belongs to, e.g. `var school = givenSection.Course.School`. Conversely, given a school, I can get the course sections belonging to the school. In code it's just a couple of references away, while in the database it's just a couple of table joins. But it gets more interesting still. Consider the next model:

```
public class Enrolment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public int CourseSectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public virtual CourseSection CourseSection { get; set; }
}
```

An `Enrolment` instance is the many-to-many bridge between students and course sections. Getting a list of enrolments for a school is multiple steps requiring multiple table joins. In a system which might become quite large in number of records, I worry about the efficiency of this setup. Then again, the application is configured for lazy loading, so maybe that's OK, I don't yet know enough about EF to be certain.

In the interest of simplicity for data retrieval, might it be ideal to reference the school from either of, or both, the `CourseSection` and `Enrolment` models? Extending it further, should all models in the hierarchy be able to directly reference the `School` they belong to?

Comment: Not really an answer, but 'Enrolments' should be spelled 'Enrollments'. Same goes for 'Enrolment'.

Comment: Not intrinsically in the database, but if some *specific* helper/convenience bridges are added that *do not affect the database model and normalization of such* then sure - *if* it makes life easier relative to writing and maintaining such helpers. However, *do not undermine SQL efficiency on the joins* (there has been half a century of research/optimizations) - and test such hypothesis if you do! SQL Server (or any other decent RDBMS) is *very efficient* at these sorts of "back-joins" up a quickly shrinking hierarchy and it eats for lunch. And speaking of lunch..

Comment: @haim770 Canadian spelling :)

Comment: @GrantPalin, pardon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that would break normalization. Your performance concern is valid but the solution cannot be known and should not be implemented prematurely and without measuring actual timings. In my opinion the data is the most important thing because chances are it will outlive the code. Therefore all else equal the good shape of the data should be e priority.